# Are traffic court prosecutors required to watch dashcam videos before presenting officers witness testimony?

Tags: united-states, traffic, discovery, prosecutorial-discretion

Dashcam video can contradict an officer's testimony or police report, so are prosecutors required to watch dashcam video before trial to ensure the officer's testimony is true?

When a discovery request is not made by defense, are prosecutors required to review all relevant accessible evidence before trial?

> The prosecutor is an administrator of justice, an advocate, and an officer of the court; the prosecutor must exercise sound discretion in the performance of his or her functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'traffic' in the tags so I'll assume it's a traffic ticket. Almost all traffic cases are different depending on the state. You don't mention which state, so I'll assume that it's a state where traffic tickets are criminal matters.

I don't believe prosecutors are required to watch the video before trial, though at least in Texas they are required to allow the defense access to all exculpatory evidence, if your video was indeed exculpatory.

When I make discovery requests, I make sure that the court gets the request and the prosecution gets a copy and certify to the court in the 'certificate of service' how it was delivered to the prosecution.

Once that happens, you ask the court to grant the discovery. The court usually grants some of it but the prosecution can oppose the requests in court.

You would usually do this in a 'pre-trial' period. If you've not gotten a request before trial that the court has ordered, you can not announce ready and give the reasons, or petition the court to require the prosecution to provide the ordered discovery items to you.

Getting anything provided to you in discovery into the court at trial is another matter. You'll need to be sure you understand how to get the court to allow your evidence into court and be prepared to show the court 'foundation' for your evidence. This means more than just showing up to trial and asking the court to 'enter xyz into evidence' - so before you ask the court to allow it, show it to the prosecutor (assuming they have not already seen it) and then show / tell the court exactly how your evidence is relevant and true and correct, etc. You'll need to look up exactly how to do this in other questions here.

Remember that this 'evidence' is just that; evidence and the prosecution may present other evidence that contradicts yours. The judge and / or jury (if allowed) gets to decide how true and trustworthy your evidence is.